# How to assign same button to different divs and manage them independently on click in typescript

Tags: jquery, html, typescript

I want to make an expand/collapse button and assign it on different divs. Here is my code :

```
let expandButtonHTML = require("!text-loader!./button.html");
...
let expandButton = frame.contents().find(".expandMenuArrow");
let topMenu = frame.contents().find(".efdRLHover");
let bottomMenu = frame.contents().find(".pbHeader");

topMenu.prepend(expandButtonHTML);
bottomMenu.prepend(expandButtonHTML);

let div = [topMenu, bottomMenu];

div.forEach(element => {
expandButton.click(function () {
                element.slideToggle("fast");

                if (expandButton.hasClass('fa fa-caret-down')) {
                    expandButton.removeClass('fa fa-caret-down');
                    expandButton.toggleClass('fa fa-caret-right');
                }
                else {
                    expandButton.removeClass('fa fa-caret-right');
                    expandButton.toggleClass('fa fa-caret-down');
                }
            });
});
```

I know that the forEach loop is going through all the elements in the array and doing the expandButton function on them , but how can I construct it so clicking the particular div executes the particular function on it ?

Clicking on topMenu expands topMenu and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to find expandButton separately for both topMenu and bottomMenu inside the loop, instead of finding it outside the loop. Perhaps this will help?

```
    div.forEach(element => {
        let expandButton = $(".expandMenuArrow", element);
        expandButton.click(function () {
            element.slideToggle("fast");

            if (expandButton.hasClass('fa fa-caret-down')) {
                expandButton.removeClass('fa fa-caret-down');
                expandButton.toggleClass('fa fa-caret-right');
            }
            else {
                expandButton.removeClass('fa fa-caret-right');
                expandButton.toggleClass('fa fa-caret-down');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The above solved my problem - as you said I had to define the expandButton within the loop and not outside .